# How to remove branding feature

Tags: branding

I have a SharePoint site that is using custom branding. I no longer want my SharePoint site branded, so I deactivated the feature, but the branding is still applied.

Is there a job I need to run to refresh something or other? How do I get vanilla SharePoint back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends whether the feature developer added clean up code in the [FeatureDeactivating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.featuredeactivating.aspx) event.

By the sounds of it the answer is no so you will need to manually reverse the changes the feature made. Obviously having access to the code would make this much easier.

At a basic level you may need to change the theme, master page, stylesheet(s) or more likely a combination of these items.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ((Site Settings --> Look and Feel --> Masterpage )) to apply default *seattle* or *oslo* masterpage theme?